# arrayname.forEach( function(element){ });

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a successfully populated array that contain string elements.

And I recently learned about the forEach() of JavaScript

```
arrayname.forEach( 
  function(element){
     // some statements
  }
);
```

How can I make it work so the "some statements" only run once every three seconds?  I tried setInterval and setTimeOut but it did not give me the result I desired. Thanks

I tried this as well

```
 arrayname.forEach( function(element){ }).delay(3000);
```

but it still did not give me the result I wanted.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = ["Microsoft", "Google", "Apple"];

var i = 0;
function loop() {
    alert( arr[i] );
    i++;
    if( i < arr.length ){
        setTimeout( loop, 3000 );
    }
};
loop();
```

Comment: Thank you this was simple but did exactly what I wanted to see

Answer (score 1):

This function will do it - it's worth avoiding `setInterval` wherever possible - it has issues where it doesn't guarantee at least `delay` between calls, particularly if earlier calls have been queued up (perhaps because the window lost focus):

```
function forEachWithDelay(arr, callback, delay, thisArg) {
    var index = 0, count = arr.length;
    (function loop() {
        if (index < count) {
            callback.call(thisArg, arr[index], index, arr); // same as .forEach
            ++index;
            setTimeout(loop, delay);
        }
    })();  // start the loop immediately
 }
```

usage:

```
forEachWithDelay(arrayname, function(element, index) {
     // do something
}), 3000);
```

NB: this will start the loop with *zero* delay for the first element.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I notice you used an anonymous function

Comment: @HeavyRain creating the outer function and the inner (*not* anonymous) function wraps up all of the logic in one parameterised function and prevents any global variables (save for `forEachWithDelay` itself) from being needed.  It also acts as an almost direct drop in replacement for `Array.prototype.forEach` per your original code.  Contrast with the answer that you've mistakenly accepted [ ;-) ] where the index `i` and array `arr` are external variables that are hard-coded inside the delay logic.  It also uses a naive method of starting the loop.

Comment: to clarify - my inner function does have a name, but it's an _immediately invoked function expression_.   It has to have a name so it can pass itself as the parameter to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want:

```
var i=0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
    if(i < arrayname.length){
        console.log(arrayname[i]);
        i++;
    }else{
        clearInterval(loop);
    }
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```
var index = 0;
var t = setInterval(function() {
  console.log(arrayname[index++]);
  if (index === arrayname.length) {
    clearInterval(t);
  }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  var array = ["first","second","third","fourth"];
  var arr_length = array.length;
  var index = 0;
  callTime();

  function callTime(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        index++;
        if(index < arr_length){
            callTime();
        } 
    },1000);
  }

 });
```